# Why can't you assign and call a block at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The following code compiles:

```
^{}();
```

And this compiles:

```
void (^x)();
(x = ^{})();
```

But this doesn't:

```
(void (^x)() = ^{})();
```

The error I get is `Expected ')'`. Is this a bug with llvm or something? It's totally holding me back from pretending Objective-C is JavaScript.

Comment: That's not so weird, since Objective-C *isn't* JavaScript

Comment: That was just a joke. In reality I'm like 90% sure they're not the same language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wouldn't make sense in a C-like language. To see why, let's build the statement from the ground up.

First, we'll use your working declaration for `x`:

```
void (^x)();
```

Now let's initialize it in the same statement:

```
void (^x)() = ^{};
```

So far so good - `x` has been initialized with the correct block. So let's invoke `x` now. But where will the `()` go? Naturally, we need to place the `()` immediately after a block-valued expression. However, in C, declarations are statements, not expressions so

```
(void (^x)() = ^{})();
```

doesn't make sense. The only place the `()` can go is after the `^{}`:

```
void (^x)() = ^{}();
```

But `^{}()` has type `void`, not type `void (^)()`.

To sum up: you can't declare a block variable and invoke it at the same time. you'll have to either declare and initialize the variable, and then call it

```
void (^x)() = ^{};
x();
```

or declare it and then assign and call it

```
void (^x)();
(x = ^{})();
```

or just separate all three:

```
void (^x)();
x = ^{};
x();
```

As a concluding thought, let's say it was desirable to declare and invoke blocks at the same time. If we decided to allow code like `(void (^x)() = ^{})();`, then for the sake of consistency, we would have to also allow code such as `++(void x = 4);` or `(void x = 1) + (void y = 2);`. I hope you'll agree that these just look strange in C.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think the weirdness of the block declaration syntax confused me a bit. It totally doesn't make sense to try to invoke the declaration. I wish the compiler could come up with something better than `Expected ')'` though :/

Comment: @AnshuChimala: I agree. When I compile the code with Clang 3.0, I get two `error: expected ')'` errors. These are followed by `error: expected expression` (referring to applying `()` to the declaration). Only the last error message is important in this case, so the fact that it is listed last might even be a bug of sorts, considering Clang's focus on improving error messages.

Comment: Please file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com/.   The Clang team is both quite responsive and very much desires to improve the error messages in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

As an analogy, consider:

This compiles:

```
if (42) { }
```

And this compiles:

```
int x;
if (x = 42) { }
```

But this doesn't:

```
if (int x = 42) { }
```